# How to filter for minus XX workdays in VBA?

Tags: vba

can you please advise on the following:

I'm trying to use VBA to filter for working days. My criteria should be: filter all dates that are older than 30 working days from today's date.

```
.Range("$A$1:$X$2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & Format(Application.Evaluate("WORKDAY(TODAY(),-30)"), "dd/mm/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

I have tried the above but it doesn't work as it should.

Need:

```
'date = today
'count -30 work days from today
'filter to display everything that is older than Date(-30 workdays from today)
```

Thanks
West

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just change the sign to `<` and it will work**

```
.Range("$A$1:$X$2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & Format(Application.Evaluate("WORKDAY(TODAY(),-30)"), "mm/dd/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

You are using > that means all the dates after that day returned by the function, but as you are interested in using all the dates prior to that date, use `<`

**Filter takes the Format `"mm/dd/yyyy"`**

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: I tried that but everything is now basically filtered, i.e. filter is applied but no data is displayed.

Comment: I think I found the Problem. Could be the Format. I have changed in the Answer now. Try it. @WestRay

Comment: It worked. How surprising given the format dd/mm/yyyy. Thanks

Comment: Can you advise how can I add another criteria to this line? I.e. Criteria2 ?

Comment: @WestRay Add `, Criteria2:="<09-07-2019"` in the end of the Function. and Change `xlAnd` to `xlOr` as per requirement

Comment: I was constantly using xlAnd instead of Or. You are my superstar :D Thanks again!